# How do I add my AppHandler to my routes?

Tags: go, gorilla

I am trying to implement an `appHandler` as described in [The Go Blog: Error handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go#TOC_3.).
I have the `appHandler`, now I'm just trying to hook it up to my routes. The following works:

```
router := new(mux.Router)
router.Handle("/my/route/", handlers.AppHandler(handlers.MyRoute))
```

But, I want to be able to allow GET requests as well as having "StrictSlash(true)". I have:

```
type Routes []Route
type Route struct {
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}


var routes = Routes{
    Route{"GET", "/my/route/", handlers.AppHandler(handlers.MyRoute)}
} 
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
for _, route := range routes {
    var handler http.Handler
    handler = route.HandlerFunc
    router.Methods(route.Method).Path(route.Pattern).Handler(handler)
}
```

AppHandler looks like:

```
type AppHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) *appError

func (fn AppHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // blah, blah, blah
}
```

I get an error:

```
cannot use handlers.AppHandler(handlers.MyRoute) (type handlers.AppHandler) as type http.HandlerFunc in field value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AppHandler` isn't a `http.HandlerFunc`, it's a `http.Handler`.

A `http.HandlerFunc` is just a function that takes both a `http.ResponseWriter` and a `*http.Request`.

`http.Handler` is an interface that is satisfied by any type that has a method `ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`

Change your struct to something like

```
type Route struct {
    Method  string
    Pattern string
    Handler http.Handler
}
```

And then at the bottom you can probably do

```
for _, route := range routes {
    router.Methods(route.Method).Path(route.Pattern).Handler(route.Handler)
}
```